# How to rotate a cylinder in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have drawn a wire cylinder in JOGL and I want to make it stand up when it is coming out of the screen?

I've been messing around with the following code in order to do the rotate but it is not rotating:

```
gl.glRotatef(cylinder_a, 0, 0, 90);
```

What is the correct way to rotate a cylinder in JOGL?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [JOGL documentation for `gl.glRotatef`](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/docs/javax/media/opengl/GL.html#glRotatef%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) its arguments are `angle`, `x`, `y`, `z`. With the arguments `0`, `0`, `90` for x, y, z, you are defining the vector along +z, pointing out of the screen. This means that you are rotating the cylinder about its axis, so the change isn't apparent. To make it stand "upright" you need to rotate it around the x axis.

(You can change the way x, y, and z point in OpenGL, but usually +x points right, +y point up, and +z "comes out" from the screen. You can use the [right hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) to remember that.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this first but nothing happened. Ive just tried it again and it hasnt moved at all, im not too sure why. It doesnt matter how large or small I make any of the values, it just doesnt move at all :/

Comment: Hmm, then it's hard to tell what the problem is unless you post code. To make a guess, though, maybe the glRotatef call is in the wrong place in your code?